# How many words in the lines?

Tags: word-usage

I'm learning.

The line containe 3 words in **I**   **'m**  **learning**.

```
echo "i'm learning" |wc -w
2
```

wc can't count  accurately.

```
echo "i'm here !" |wc -w 
3
```

Does character ! belong  word in english??

There are tow lines :450th and 805th line in rime.txt.

> 450:     And now 'twas like all instruments,
>   805:      'Tis sweeter far to me

How many words in the two lines?
**And now 'twas like all instruments,** contains 6 words?
**'Tis sweeter far to me** contains 5 words?

[sample txt--rime.txt](https://github.com/michaeljamesfitzgerald/Introducing-Regular-Expressions/blob/master/rime.txt)

Comment: Depends on what you call a word... I'm curious why it matters. What bearing does this have on the process of learning English?

Comment: to write a program to count all words in the article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I'm" is one word, not two.

Wikipedia [offers these indicators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word#Word_boundaries) for the boundary between words:

- **Potential pause** --- In English it is not possible to pause in the middle of a contraction.
- **Indivisibility** --- In English it is not possible to add additional words in the middle of a contraction without first replacing it with its uncontracted multi-word form.
- **Phonetic boundaries** --- English does not have specific phonetic markers for the beginning and ends of words, so this does not apply to English.
- **Orthographic boundaries** --- English orthography indicates separations between words with spaces. No spaces are present in a contraction.

Comment: echo  "i'm here !" |wc -w  ---result is 3.

Comment: character  such as ! is a word ?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature, `wc` has been part of Unix since the 1970's. It isn't a sophisticated AI natural-language parser. It just counts blocks of non-whitespace separated by whitespace. Questions about the details of how `wc` works will get better answers at [Super User](https://superuser.com/) than here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a *nix system, including Mac OSX

> [wc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wc_(Unix))

will give you the word count as the second number, the first is the number of lines, the third number is the character count.

Comment: The line containe 3 words in I 'm learning.

Comment: echo "i'm learning" |wc -w ,the result is 2.

Comment: wc can't count accurately.

Comment: "I'm" is one word.